# Ping a server with Rails and showing the status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scheduling, ping

I am currently creating a Dashboard app which is created with Ruby on Rails.

I have added a Server model and controller and the same for Ping.

What I want is to run the `ping` command on the given server IP address.

How would I go about this and log the results (status and M/S) into the database?

I would also like to know how to run the command every minute.

Comment: I'd be tempted to create a rake task that did this and simply cron it to run every minute...  Hard to tell without knowing more details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to open a TCP socket:

```
require 'timeout'
require 'socket'

def ping(host)
  begin
    Timeout.timeout(5) do 
      s = TCPSocket.new(host, 'echo')
      s.close
      return true
    end
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED 
    return true
  rescue Timeout::Error, Errno::ENETUNREACH, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
    return false
  end
end

ping('109.104.109.237')
```

These uses TCP ping rather than ICMP so a firewall would need to be configured as appropriate.

Running this every minute can be achieve using something like:

```
loop do
  # do your ping tests
  sleep 60
end
```

and running that process all the time. You can look at something like Daemons (http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) if you want an easy way to background it.

Comment: An editor suggested a change to your Answer. Please see the edit history, and act as you feel fit.